# Add fiddler certificate to Squid proxy

Tags: https, fiddler, squid

I want to add fiddler certificate to decode HTTPS traffic on my Android mobile. But I don't want to user PIN lockscreen. It is possible to add fiddler certificate to squid proxy ?
My scheme is
Android device -> Squid Proxy -> Fiddler

Answer (score 0):

If your squid proxy runs on linux box, Linux certificates will be of type .pem

Fiddler root certificate will be of windows native form i guess.

For decryption you can generate intermediate linux certificate and using that certificate you can tell squid to bump all https traffic hitting the proxy.
But you need to install the corresponding root certificate in all devices that connects to that proxy or else you will get security warning about man in middle attack